# Find the six trigonometric functions given a point with $y=2x$

Tags: trigonometry

The terminal side of the angle θ is standard position lies on the given line and satisfies the given condition. Determine the 6 trigonometric functions of said angle.

$$y = 2x,  \quad   \sec θ > 0$$

I know how to find the trig functions from radians and angles, but it's the first time I see this type of question.

I know that an angle in standard position means it's initial side is on the positive x axis and the vertex is on the origin, the other ray is the terminal side. I know $y=2x$ is linear and that $\sec θ > 0$ means the angle is positive (rotates counterclockwise). I don't know how to go on beyond that.

Comment: **HINT**: The slope of the straight line $y=2x$ is equal to $\tan(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle that this line makes with the $x$ axes.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Even if this is the first time for you to see this kind of problem, state a few facts that you know that relate to this problem.

Comment: One thing to explain is, how much of this is new to you? Do you know what it means for an angle to be "in standard position"? Do you know what is the "terminal side" of such an angle? This can help determine whether an answer just explains the vocabulary but expects you to work the rest of the problem, or whether it gives some hints to apply _after_ you say what the words mean.

Comment: Hint: think about the problem

Comment: I'm going to edit this into my post as well. I know that an angle in standard position means it's initial side is on the positive x axis and the vertex is on the origin, the other ray is the terminal side. I know y=2x is linear and that secθ > 0 means the angle is positive (rotates counterclockwise). I don't know how to go on beyond that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Use the diagram to determine the point where the line $y = 2x$ intersects the unit circle.  Note that $\sec\theta > 0 \implies  \cos\theta > 0 \implies x > 0$.

[image: point_of_intersection_of_the_line_with_the_unit_circle]